# Joomla 3: How to uninstall module from a package?

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

In my package, I have a module and a plugin. When I uninstall a package from the `Extension Manager`, the plugin gets uninstalled but the module remains there. Also the package entry gets removed from the `Extension Manager`. Then I have to manually uninstall the module. I get the following messages:

```
Warning
Attempting to uninstall unknown extension from package. 
This extension may have already been removed earlier.


Message
Uninstalling package was successful.
```

How do I ensure the module gets uninstalled when I uninstall the package?

**UPDATE:**

My package manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<extension type="package" version="3.0">
<name>RR Test One Package</name>
<author>John Doe</author>
<creationDate>November 2013</creationDate>
<packagename>rr_test_one_package</packagename>
<version>1.0</version>
<packager>John Doe</packager>
<description>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</description>
<files folder="packages">
    <file type="module" id="rr_test_one" client="site">mod_rr_test_one.zip</file>
    <file type="plugin" id="rr_test_one" group="content">plg_content_rr_test_one.zip</file>
</files>
</extension>
```

I have `script.php` inside the plugin and module folders to make some updates to the database entries. The plugin uninstalls without the uninstall function when I uninstall the package. It's just not uninstalling the module. Do I need to have another `script.php` in the `packages` folder along with the package manifest and have the `uninstall` function in the script.php?

Comment: assuming you have a script.php within your package, can you provide the code you already have for the uninstall function?

Comment: also the manifest for the package

Comment: Please see the update above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was the `id` in the `<file>` tag of the module type that was giving out the warning. I added `mod_` in the id. Below is what I did and this resolved the issue.

```
<files folder="packages">
  <file type="module" id="mod_rr_test_one" client="site">mod_rr_test_one.zip</file>
  <file type="plugin" id="rr_test_one" group="content">plg_content_rr_test_one.zip</file>
</files>
```

Comment: i am stuck too, here is my post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24636683/uninstalling-joomla-package-not-uninstalling-all-child-extensions not working even i followed your way. do you know why?