# uninstalling joomla package not uninstalling all child extensions

Tags: php, joomla2.5, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I created a joomla package including all component and module zips inside packages folder of the package. all required settings in package xml file as follows -

```
<extension type="package" version="2.5" method="upgrade">
........
<packagename>mypackage</packagename>
........
<files folder="packages">
    <filename type="module" id="mypackage">Ajax-Session-Module-master.zip</filename>
    <filename type="component" id="mypackage">component-develop.zip</filename>
</files>
.......
```

When i install package, i see those above package modules and components installed well, but when i uninstall package from extension manager->manage page , package uninstalled well but those package modules and components not uninstalled automatically!.

Where is wrong i just not getting, as i got from web that i have to put filename id as the package name in package xml file above, so is did but it did not resolved the issue. Fyi this package will be for both joomla 2.5 and 3. Please lead me to right direction asap.

Comment: no one? what's wrong, is that a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in the extension package, you should use `<file ...>` instead of `<filename ...>`. I tried something like this in my package xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<extension type="package" version="3.0">
......
......
......
<files folder="packages">
    <file type="module" id="mod_rr_test_one" client="site">mod_rr_test_one.zip</file>
    <file type="plugin" id="rr_test_one" group="content">plg_content_rr_test_one.zip</file>
</files>
```

Comment: My primary test shows it's being uninstalled. Thanks for saving times.